# Minipage Height as an Argument

Tags: minipage

How can I make the vertical rule as long as the height of the minipage next to it? I don't want to have to test manually the height argument and find the one that fits.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
Hello
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}%
%
\hspace{1pt}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1.5ex}{\rule{1pt}{3cm}}
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.80\textwidth}
Hello
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the low level `\vrule` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\mbox{\vrule width 1pt \hspace{3pt}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.80\textwidth}
  Hello\\
  Here\\
  is\\
  a rule
  \end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

If `height` and `depth` are not specified, the rule adjusts itself to the height and depth of the enclosing box.

[image]