# Multi-line node with height only dependent on number of lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want the height of a multi-line TikZ node to depend only on the number of lines it contains, not on whether the text on the first and last line is `aaa` or `aAq` (the famous height and depth problem).

I tried adding `\strut` (or `\vphantom{Aq}`) before and after the node text to ensure the first and last line have the full height, but this doesn't work well if the node text starts/ends with an empty line or a list environment and probably other things. Fixing the node height as proposed for many similar questions here doesn't work either because I don't know how many lines there will be.

So, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Try `text depth=.2em`....

Comment: This only works for the depth part of the problem, not the height. Also, is there some sort of convention that the text depth is always 0.2em?

Comment: You can't find a solution for all cases! It depends of the content (see for example [Minipage Height as an Argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350941/14500) or [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/14500)).

Comment: Is there no way how I could tell the strut to never ever be in a paragraph on its own, independent of what follows/precedes it?

Comment: Ask a similar question in the context of TeX boxes. If someone find a solution, you have your answer in the context of TikZ nodes.